# Sending an Email via Python

Tags: python, email, smtplib

I'm attempting to send an email with Python. From what I can tell, all the following code needs is a valid recipient and a host **HOST**. I'm unsure on how to get the host. What is the simplest way?

```
import smtplib
import string

SUBJECT = "Test email from Python"
TO = "python@mydomain.com"
FROM = "python@mydomain.com"
text = "blah blah blah"
BODY = string.join((
        "From: %s" % FROM,
        "To: %s" % TO,
        "Subject: %s" % SUBJECT ,
        "",
        text
        ), "\r\n")
server = smtplib.SMTP(HOST)
server.sendmail(FROM, [TO], BODY)
server.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HOST is the SMTP relay provided by your ISP (typically related to the domain name of your from address).  If you use a desktop mail client, you'll be able to see the SMTP server listed in your mail settings.  If you're hosting using shared hosting, your hosting provider should be able to provide an SMTP server for you to use.